# numpy - why numerical gradient log(1-sigmoid(x)) diverges but log(sigmoid(x)) does not?

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point

## Question

Why the numeric gradient `(f(x+k)-f(x-k)) / 2k` of the logistic log loss function `f(x) = -np.log(1.0 - __sigmoid(x))` diverges but `-np.log(__sigmoid(x))` does not? What are the potential cases and mechanisms or am I making mistakes? The code is at the bottom.

Any suggestion, correction, insights, resources references, or advice/tip/hint on how to implement the numeric gradient will be appreciated.

[image]

## Background

Trying to implement a numeric gradient `(f(x+k)-f(x-k)) / 2k`  of the logistic log loss function. `y` in the figure is binary true/false label `T` and `p` is the activation `sigmoid(x)`.

[Logistic log loss functions](https://ml-cheatsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/loss_functions.html)

[image]

When `k` is relatively large such as `1e-5`, the issue does not happen, at least in the range of `x`.

[image]

However when `k` gets smaller e.g. `1e-08`, `-np.log(1.0 - __sigmoid(x))` started diverging. However, it does not happen to  `-np.log(__sigmoid(x))`.

Wonder if subtracting `1.0 - sigmoid(x)` has something to do with in relation to how float numbers are stored and calculated in a computer in the [binary manner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754).

The reason trying to make `k` smaller is to prevent `log(0)` to become `np.inf` by adding a small number `u` e.g. `1e-5` but `log(x+1e-5)` causes a deviation of numerical gradient from the analytical one. To minimize the impact, I try to make it smallest possible and start having this issue.

[image]

## Code

### Logistic log loss and analytical gradient.

```
import numpy as np
import inspect
from itertools import product
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

def __sigmoid(X):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-1 * X))

def __logistic_log_loss(X: np.ndarray, T: np.ndarray):
    return -(T * np.log(__sigmoid(X)) + (1-T) * np.log(1-__sigmoid(X)))

def __logistic_log_loss_gradient(X, T):
    Z = __sigmoid(X)
    return Z-T

N = 1000
left=-20
right=20

X = np.linspace(left,right,N)
T0 = np.zeros(N)
T1 = np.ones(N)

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# T = 1
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
ax.plot(
    X,
    __logistic_log_loss(X, T1),
    color='blue', linestyle='solid',
    label="logistic_log_loss(X, T=1)"
)
ax.plot(
    X, 
    __logistic_log_loss_gradient(X, T1),
    color='navy', linestyle='dashed',
    label="Analytical gradient(T=1)"
)

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# T = 0
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ax.plot(
    X, 
    __logistic_log_loss(X, T0), 
    color='magenta', linestyle='solid',
    label="logistic_log_loss(X, T=0)"
)
ax.plot(
    X, 
    __logistic_log_loss_gradient(X, T0),
    color='purple', linestyle='dashed', 
    label="Analytical gradient(T=0)"
)

ax.set_xlabel("X")
ax.set_ylabel("dL/dX")
ax.set_title("Logistic log loss and gradient")
ax.legend()
ax.grid(True)
```

[image]

### Numerical gradient

```
def t_0_loss(X):
    return [
        #logistic_log_loss(P=sigmoid(x), T=0)
        -np.log(1.0 - __sigmoid(x)) for x in X 
    ]

def t_1_loss(X):
    return [
        #logistic_log_loss(P=sigmoid(x), T=1)
        -np.log(__sigmoid(x)) for x in X 
    ]

N = 1000
left=-1
right=15

# Numerical gradient
# (f(x+k)-f(x-k)) / 2k 
k = 1e-9

X = np.linspace(left,right,N)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10,8))

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# T = 0
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
axes[0].plot(
    X,
    ((np.array(t_0_loss(X + k)) - np.array(t_0_loss(X - k))) / (2*k)),
    color='red', linestyle='solid',
    label="Diffed numerical gradient(T=0)"
)
axes[0].plot(
    X[0:-1:20],
    ((np.array(t_0_loss(X + k)) - np.array(t_0_loss(X))) / k)[0:-1:20],
    color='black', linestyle='dotted', marker='x', markersize=4,
    label="Left numerical gradient(T=0)"
)
axes[0].plot(
    X[0:-1:20],
    ((np.array(t_0_loss(X)) - np.array(t_0_loss(X - k))) / k)[0:-1:20],
    color='salmon', linestyle='dotted', marker='o', markersize=5,
    label="Right numerical gradient(T=0)"
)

axes[0].set_xlabel("X")
axes[0].set_ylabel("dL/dX")
axes[0].set_title("T=0: -log(1-sigmoid(x))")
axes[0].legend()
axes[0].grid(True)

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# T = 1
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
axes[1].plot(
    X,
    ((np.array(t_1_loss(X + k)) - np.array(t_1_loss(X - k))) / (2*k)),
    color='blue', linestyle='solid',
    label="Diffed numerical gradient(T=1)"
)
axes[1].plot(
    X[0:-1:20],
    ((np.array(t_1_loss(X + k)) - np.array(t_1_loss(X))) / k)[0:-1:20],
    color='cyan', linestyle='dashed', marker='x', markersize=5,
    label="Left numerical gradient(T=1)"
)
axes[1].plot(
    X[0:-1:20],
    ((np.array(t_1_loss(X)) - np.array(t_1_loss(X - k))) / k)[0:-1:20],
    color='yellow', linestyle='dotted', marker='o', markersize=5,
    label="Right numerical gradient(T=1)"
)

axes[1].set_xlabel("X")
axes[1].set_ylabel("dL/dX")
axes[1].set_title("T=1: -log(sigmoid(x)")
axes[1].legend()
axes[1].grid(True)
```

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest using `f(x) = -np.log1p( - __sigmoid(x))` that's exactly what log1p is made for...

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a real number is converted to (or computed in) any limited-precision numerical format, there may be some amount of error. Suppose that, in a particular interval, the numerical format is capable of representing values with a precision of one part in *P*. In other words, the numbers that are representable in the format appear at distances that are about 1/*P* apart relative to the magnitudes of the numbers.

Then, when a real number is converted to the format, resulting in a representable number, the error (ignoring sign) may be at most ½ of 1/*P* (relative to the magnitude) if we choose the nearest representable number. It may be smaller, if the real number happens to be on or near a representable number.

Now consider your expression `f(x+k)-f(x-k)`. `f(x+k)` and `f(x-k)` will have some error around ¼ of 1/*P*, maybe more if they are the results of several calculations, maybe less if you are lucky. But, for a simple model, we can figure the error will be somewhere in the region of 1/*P*. When we subtract them, the error may still be somewhere in the region of 1/*P*. The errors in `f(x+k)` and `f(x-k)` may reinforce or may cancel in the subtraction, so sometimes you will get very little total error, but it will often about somewhere around 1/*P*.

In your situation, `f(x+k)` and `f(x-k)` are very near each other. So, when they are subtracted, the result is much smaller in magnitude than they are. That error of around 1/*P* is relative to the magnitudes of `f(x+k)` and `f(x-k)`. Since `f(x+k)-f(x-k)` is very small compared to `f(x+k)` and `f(x-k)`, the error of 1/*P* relative to `f(x+k)` and `f(x-k)` is much larger relative to `f(x+k)-f(x-k)`.

This is the source of most of the noise in your graph.

To avoid it, you need to calculate `f(x+k)-f(x-k)` with more precision or you need to avoid that calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Solution by Reza.B.

> Let z=1/(1+p), p= e^(-x). You can see then log(1-z)=log(p)-log(1+p), which is more stable in terms of rounding errors (we got rid of division, which is the main issue in numerical instabilities).

## Reformulation

[image]

## Result

The errors have been resolved.

```
def t_0_loss(X):
    L = X + np.log(1 + np.exp(-X))
    return L.tolist()

def t_1_loss(X):
    L = np.log(1 + np.exp(-X))
    return L.tolist()

%%timeit
((np.array(t_0_loss(X + k)) - np.array(t_0_loss(X - k))) / (2*k))
((np.array(t_1_loss(X + k)) - np.array(t_1_loss(X - k))) / (2*k))
---
599 µs ± 65.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

[image]

Previous erroneous version was:

```
47 ms ± 617 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```